# Scala case matching Any with String

Tags: scala

When I try to match an `Any` with a String, I don't get the correct output. My code looks like:

```
def typecast(cls: Any) {
    cls match {
        case s: String => println("string")
        case d: Double => println("double")
        case i: Int => println("int")
        case o: Option[_] => println("option")
        case _ => println("nothing")
    }
}
```

If `cls` is of type `Double` or `Int`, the correct case is matched, but of type `String` or `Option[_]` the case _ is matched (println("nothing")).

Any ideas why this isn't working or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** it works fine, if I do e.g. `typecast("foo")` or `typecast(Some("foo"))`, but in my case the `cls` value is received like:

`val cls: Any = classOf[User].getDeclaredField("name")`

where the field could be a `String` or `Option[String]`

Comment: works like a charm for me, typecast("foo") prints "string", typecast(None) and typecast(Some("stuff")) print "option".

Comment: just recognized, that this just happens in my special case. I edited the question. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your updating question : the code works as it should.

`classOf[User].getDeclaredField` does not return a `String` or whatever, it returns a `java.lang.reflect.Field`. Which is rightly dealt with by `case _`. You could get value of type `java.lang.class`, or `java lang.reflect.Type` by calling getType or getGenericType on that.

However, even then, your routine does not expect values of type `Class`, it expects plain values, of type `String` or `Int` or `Double`... "cls" does not sound like a good argument name there.

A routine expecting classes would look like

```
def typecast(cls: Class[_]) { // will work with cls: Any too
  if(cls == classOf[Int]) println("Int")
  else if(cls == classOf[String]) println("String")
  else if(cls == classOf[Option[_]]) println("Option")
  else println("Nothing")
}
```

Be careful too that a field may be declared of class `Option`, but there are no direct instances of class `Option` which is abstract, there are only instances of `Some` and the `None` object.

Comment: thanks for your answer! for sure, I have to call getType(). it works when the function expects `Class[_]`